# How is pressure related to time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, time, dimensional-analysis

I was studying physics for my exams when I came up with a question:

there is this relationship $1Pa=1kg/(m*s^2)$ , which I reckon to be true as you can define pressure as $F/A$ and also by Newton's second law, $F=ma$ so the unit will be $kg.(m/s^2)/m^2$ which is $kg/(m*s^2)$

I'm guessing there must be a relationship between time (because of the $s^2$) and pressure, but I can't figure out how it's supposed to work with the basic knowledge and understanding I have. (My idea of pressure is only force per area)
I also tried searching across the web, and came back with no answers.

So the question is: *is* there a connection, and if so, how is it explained?

I would genuinely appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Do you know the difference between force and net force?  Do you feel that whenever two quantities have the same units, they must be related?

Comment: Why was this closed? It isn't unclear at all.

Comment: It's interesting to contemplate how one would use a clock to measure pressure. Certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between pressure and time is simply in the [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) of pressure, which tell us that units of pressure have dimensions $M^1L^{-1}T^{-2}$.

If we were to change our basic unit of time to be, for example, the millisecond ($10^{-3}$ seconds) rather than the second then our measurements of time intervals would become numerically $10^3$ times larger. For consistency, the unit of pressure (now kg per metre per *millisecond* squared) would have to become larger by a factor of  $10^{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

Pressure may or may not be related to time, depending on whether or not it accelerates something. As @Chet Miller pointed out, two quantities having the same units are not necessarily related.

In this case, keep in mind that the force in Newton's second law $F=ma$ is the *net force* acting on mass. For clarity it should be written $F_{net}=ma$. That's because not all forces produce acceleration, only net forces. If I push against a wall with a force the wall doesn’t accelerate, yet I apply pressure to it.

Another example are two quantities (both involving force) with units newton meters ($N\cdot m$). Newton meters may be units for work (energy units), but they are also units for torque, which may or may not do work.  Only net torque can produce work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Pressure is relevant in many other contexts as well, but here is one example. The pressure exerted on a wall by a (nonrelativistic, single-component) gas is

- the mass of the gas particles
- times the frequency of particle collisions with the wall (*this gives one factor of inverse time*)
- times the particles' average velocity change in each collision with the wall (*this gives another factor of inverse time, since velocity is distance per time*)
- divided by the area of the wall.